# Are the < > signs considered a statement?

Tags: logic

I know they are relations or a relation of order, but are they statements?

Meaning do you use double arrows or an equality sign in the following

X < Y ⇔ ((X≤Y) ^ (X≠Y))

Or

X < Y = ((X≤Y) ^ (X≠Y))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are real numbers, then $X<Y \iff (X \leq Y) \wedge (X \neq Y)$.

"$X<Y$" is a statement. Reason: $a<b$ is either "True" or "False", just like equality.

For example:

$\mathbf{S1}: 1<2 \ $:  A "True" Statement.

$\mathbf{S2}: 3<2\ $: A "False" Statement.

Now, denote the statement $X<Y$ by $K_1$ and $(X \leq Y) \wedge (X \neq Y)$ by $K_2$.

To denote the logical equality we can use $K_1 \iff K_2$ or $K_1=K_2$.

Further reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equality

Comment: As far as I have learned, we use the equality to show (atleast in set theory) that two sets have the same elements thus they are equal. However the double arrows point out that a specific statement holds the same value (True/False) to the other. So as far as I have learned from "Settheory" is that K1=K2 is not the same as K1⟺K2

Comment: To avoid the ambiguity that arises when written in the form you mentioned. This is why I believe $\iff$ is used almost everywhere (as far as I have seen). In the "domain" of statements, $K_1= K_2$ is perfectly fine, because they essentially denote the same thing.

Comment: But, you are referring to the equality of statements only, but not that of the numbers $X$ and $Y$ involved. To distinguish it, we preserve the symbol $\iff$ for statements (convention)